# How to alter the global broadcast address (255.255.255.255) behavior on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, ip

## Desired behavior

When an application sends a packet to the global broadcast IP address `255.255.255.255`, I would like that the packet be sent to the Ethernet global broadcast address (`ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`), on all interfaces.

On Linux and probably other OSes as well this seems to work. Windows XP and Windows 7 exhibit different behaviors about this, and neither behaviour is desirable for my situation.

## Windows XP behavior

The packet will be sent correctly to the first network interface (interface order is specified in "Network Connections/Advanced/Advanced Settings"). It will also be sent to the other interfaces.

Everything is right so far. Problem is, when sending to the other interfaces, the source address of the broadcast packet is the IP address of the first interface. For example, imagine this network configuration (order is important):

- Adapter 1: IP address `192.168.0.1`
- Adapter 2: IP address `10.0.0.1`
- Adapter 3: IP address `172.17.0.1`

Now if I send a broadcast packet, the following packets will be sent (with source and destination IP addresses):

- On adapter 1: `192.168.0.1` => `255.255.255.255`
- On adapter 2: `192.168.0.1` => `255.255.255.255`
- On adapter 3: `192.168.0.1` => `255.255.255.255`

  In practice, applications using broadcast packets won't work on any interfaces other than adapter 1. In my opinion, this is a blatant bug in the TCP/IP stack of Windows XP.

## Windows 7 behavior

Modifying the network interface order doesn't seem to have any effect on Windows 7. Instead, broadcast seems to be controlled by the IP route table.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   10.202.254.254       10.202.1.2    286
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.3     10
       10.202.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link        10.202.1.2    286
       10.202.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.202.1.2    286
   10.202.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.202.1.2    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.3    266
      192.168.0.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.3    266
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.3    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.3    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.202.1.2    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.3    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.202.1.2    286
===========================================================================
```

See the `255.255.255.255` routes? Yep, they control broadcast packets. In this situation, broadcast packets will be send via the `192.168.0.3` because it has the lower metric... but not to the other interfaces.

You can change the interface through which global broadcast packets will be sent very easily (just add a persistent `255.255.255.255` route with a low metric). But no matter how hard you try, broadcast packets will only be sent on only *one* interface, not all of them like I'd like it to do.

## Conclusion

- Windows 7 only sends broadcast packets to one interface. You can choose which one, but that's not the point here.
- Windows XP sends broadcast packets to all interfaces, but it only sends them as expected to one interface, which in practice is equivalent to the Windows 7 behavior.

## The goal

I want to change this global IP broadcast support in Windows (preferably Windows 7) once and for all. Of course the better way would be to have some kind of supported configuration change (registry hack or similar), but I'm open to all suggestions.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you using to generate these broadcasts.  I can't get my XP stack to do anything but directed broadcasts. i.e. 10.202.255.255 in your case.

Comment: Can you reference an RFC or other document that indicates the Correct Behavior you describe? While I agree it's desired behavior, to call it correct behavior should reference a spec that defines what is correct. Could it be that the specific routing implementation is left up to the provider (Microsoft in this case)?

Comment: Scott Lundberg: many applications (especially games) will send global broadcast. You can generate some using netcat: "nc -v -u 255.255.255.255 5000" for example.

Comment: Jason R. Coombs: indeed, maybe I had a poor choice of words. I should have used "desirable behavior". I don't think there is a RFC for this, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Are you sending a TCP or UDP packet?  According to this that matters http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/peertopeer/thread/f27f84a2-31dc-4532-9fc8-23d2dc9b4cdb.

Comment: UDP, obviously. You can't broadcast with TCP for obvious reasons. The link you provided is interesting, though: it does explain the behavior (last message of d.vasanth) but it doesn't say how to "fix" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved it programmatically. I wrote a tiny software called [WinIPBroadcast](https://github.com/dechamps/WinIPBroadcast) which takes care of relaying the broadcast frames to all interfaces.

It works using an interesting fact: it is possible to receive locally generated global broadcast packets when listening on the loop back address (127.0.0.1). WinIPBroadcast listens on the local address for all broadcast using RAW sockets, then for each broadcast packet, it relays it to all interfaces except the preferred one.

Update 06.12.2021: Updated Link for the community

Comment: As the windows stack is a fork of the BSD stack, I'm curious to know if BSD exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: Your software doesn't work. `The program can't start becuase api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll is missing from your computer.`. Good luck finding that `.dll` on Google.

Comment: @AlexG: that's weird, I thought I had fixed that problem through https://github.com/dechamps/WinIPBroadcast/commit/4dfab9ca94b9a871882c8cf789ca626b370b76f8. Are you sure you are running the last version (1.6)? Feel free to file a bug at https://github.com/dechamps/WinIPBroadcast/issues and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 7):

Not that I am in the business of defending Microsoft, but after reading through the following RFCs which attempt to define how broadcasts work, I don't think that Microsoft is necessarily violating any RFCs.  IMO the problem should be fixed at the application level (i.e. directed broadcasts, not global) which will hit the appropriate routes in the routing table and only be sent from the correct interface for that IP network.

- [RFC922](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc922)
- [RFC919](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc919)

They both state that there is no standard defined for broadcasts.  It also mentions in 919 that a specific physical interface should be selected for the broadcast.  In the case of a multi-homed, multi-NIC machine generating the broadcast, I don't think that it's clearly stated what should happen.  Broadcasts are never supposed to be passed by routers from one interface to the other, so is the Windows machine a router or not in this case?
If it is *acting* as a router, then any host responding to the broadcast with the incorrect IP address for that network (Adapters 2 and 3 in your example) should send the packet back to  the ethernet address of Adapters 2 and 3 in response to Adapter 1's IP address and the Windows host should route it to the proper interface.
*That sounds confusing... but can't think of a better way to phrase this*

And finally, RFC 919 specifically says
*From RFC 919*

> Since we assume that the problem
> has    already been solved at the data
> link layer, an IP host wishing to
> send either a local broadcast or a
> directed broadcast need only
> specify the appropriate destination
> address and send the datagram as
> usual.  Any sophisticated algorithms
> need only reside in gateways.

Reading that would suggest that the source IP address is irrelevant for a broadcast.


Since each application seems to handle broadcasts differently, I think that's where the responsibility resides.  For example.  `nbtstat` sends out directed broadcasts on multi-NICed machines, whereas games might use global broadcasts.
In short, the application should be fixed, not the OS in this case...

EDIT:  Here is a [link](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0011.0/0367.html) for the same circumstances, but on Linux.  The linux kernel handles it by only sending one packet out the default interface (NIC A in this example).  They recommend that the application enumerate the NICs and send a **directed** broadcast out each NIC.  [Link](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0011.0/0367.html)

Comment: In don't understand the relation between the paragraph you're quoting from RFC 919 and the source address. It seems obvious to me that it is *always* wrong to send an IP packet on an interface with the source address of another interface, regardless of the broadcast/unicast nature of the packet. I mean, you can't reasonably say "the source IP address is irrelevant for a broadcast", of course it is! How else are applications supposed to know who sent the broadcast?

Comment: "It also mentions in 919 that a specific physical interface should be selected for the broadcast." Where? "The address 255.255.255.255 denotes a broadcast on a local hardware network" (RFC919 7.)? In that case I respectfully disagree. We're discussing what to do with broadcasts at the host level, not at the network level. Besides, it is said just below that a host may "broadcast to all of its immediate neighbors by using 255.255.255.255". *All* its immediate neighbours. Not "all the neighbours on a specific network interface".

Comment: By the way, the point of the question is not really to discuss the standardized behavior, but the behavior 99% of the applications out there expect. If 99% of the applications expect to be able to send global broadcasts to all interfaces at once, then we can reasonably say this behavior is a de facto standard (especially considering the RFCs are not very clear about this subject). When you're listing LAN servers in a multiplayer games, you expect it to query all network interfaces. Not just one of them, that just doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you prefer, you can rewrite the question to yourself "How to fix the global broadcast address behavior on Windows" to "How to make global broadcast address send on all interfaces on Windows" to make it more "neutral". I don't really care if it's violating a standard or not (though it certainly is interesting), I need to make things work and I don't have control other the application.

Comment: Applications don't care which interface sent the broadcast.  They just need to respond to it.  If a packet can't get to another network, then a IP route needs to be formed so that it can.  Build a route between Network B and Network A and then the response will get through.

Comment: Concerning the de facto standard.  I think the reason this is such a gray answer is that there is no standard.  Each application does it differently.  In short, there is no way to fix the OS.

Comment: Concerning "the broadcast to all of its immediate neighbors"  It's in the context of a physical LAN interface, not an IP stack interface.  I am not sure, but I think that the OS is seeing 255.255.255.255 request and saying that it needs to send that out on all interfaces (to find all immediate neighbors), but it was requested from a specific application, bound to a specific IP (might be default based on metric).

Comment: BTW, I did not downpoint you.  I think this is a great question.  It's something that has never come up in my 15 years of network diagnosis and programming...

Comment: "Applications don't care which interface sent the broadcast. They just need to respond to it." Huh... they need to send broadcasts too, not only respond to them. Consider the case of a LAN gameserver browser. It sends broadcast packets to discover game servers on the network. If the broadcast packets are not sent to all interfaces, the gameserver browser will not show game servers reachable through these interfaces. In other words, epic fail.

Comment: "Concerning "the broadcast to all of its immediate neighbors" It's in the context of a physical LAN interface, not an IP stack interface." So this RFC portion isn't applicable to this discussion, because we're not at the physical level yet (in fact, we're just before the physical level).

Comment: "I am not sure, but I think that the OS is seeing 255.255.255.255 request and saying that it needs to send that out on all interfaces (to find all immediate neighbors), but it was requested from a specific application, bound to a specific IP (might be default based on metric)." I agree. That doesn't mean it's the Right Thing To Do. In my opinion it completely violates the principle of least surprise from the point of view of the application developer, who just expects to have the packet sent to everyone on all interfaces.

Comment: RE: "Huh... they need to send broadcasts too, not only respond to them."  I disagree.  They will not need to send a broadcast in response to a broadcast.  They already know who sent the broadcast and they just respond to it directly to the source IP.  Try setting up a route between Network B and Network A.  I am 99% sure your game will then start to work properly.

Comment: RE:"So this RFC portion isn't applicable to this discussion, because we're not at the physical level yet."  Exactly! We are at level 3 of the OSI when the application requests a packet to be sent to 255.255.255.255.  The application is not taking into account multiple interfaces and so it is only requesting 1 packet be sent, not three.  The OS knows that it needs to follow the RFC and send this to all known LAYER 2 neighbors, so it does, but it only sends it as one packet on three interfaces.  Would you have it generate multiple packets when the application did not request that?

Comment: "They will not need to send a broadcast in response to a broadcast. They already know who sent the broadcast and they just respond to it directly to the source IP." Of course. I interpreted "respond to broadcast" as "answer a broadcast packet with a unicast packet". Apparently this was just a misunderstanding. Moving on.

Comment: "Try setting up a route between Network B and Network A." I'm not sure what you mean by that. Besides I don't necessarily want my two networks to be reachable from each other.

Comment: "Would you have it generate multiple packets when the application did not request that?" In the case of a broadcast packet, the application *did request* to generate multiple packets: the packet will be duplicated multiple times to reach all the hosts on the network, that's the whole point of broadcast! The fact that packets get duplicated on the host or farther in the network isn't important, they will get duplicated anyway. The application acknowledged that the moment it sent a packet to a broadcast address.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by duplicated.  The RFCs specifically forbid forwarding of broadcast packets.  There should only be one packet sent, which I think is the whole crux of our discussion.  If the OS were to do as you say, it would actually have to generate 9 total packets (3 for each interface) because the IP layer would have to generate three packets with separate source IPs (one for each NIC at Layer 3) and then each NIC would have to send those out on the Ethernet (Layer 2).  If there were routes between networks, then you get 3 responses back!  Which one is right?

Comment: Please see my edit in my original answer for more info on other OSes.

Comment: I think you're right. When I was speaking about duplicating about, I was talking about layer 2 (Ethernet), where the broadcast packets are duplicated by the network switches. But you're absolutely right: my network interfaces represent several layer 3 (IP) networks, so the decision has to be taken at layer 3. At layer 3 the broadcast packet is handled like any other packet, and is sent through the appropriate interface according to the routing table...

Comment: Okay, so now I know that the behavior I want is non-standard. Still doesn't solve my problem. Even though Windows/Linux behavior is correct, I still want to send broadcast packets using all interfaces.

Comment: I still don't get it. 255.255.255.255/32 (a limited broadcast) for me, would mean: if the application (at layer 7) generated a packet with the destination address: 255.255.255.255/32, then the desired behavior would be to _duplicate_ this packet _before_ it enters L3 (or, L3 implementation should just duplicate that packet _at_ L3), so the packet is sent on all L2 interfaces of our machine. I also don't get why there are 'limited broadcast' entries in the routing table in the first place. Shouldn't the packet with a limited broadcast just _skip_ the routing table and be processed at L2?

Comment: from RFC 1122: on limited broadcast packet: "A datagram with this [255.255.255.255/32] destination address will be received by every host on the connected _physical_ network but will not be forwarded outside that network." To me, the \_physical\_ network is one layer \_below\_ L2 network. A physical network to me is something like this: every host can at one time be connected to only \_one \_physical\_ network, and the definition of the \_physical\_ (L1) network, to me, is all of the wires coming out of my PC. Maybe my definition of the physical network is wrong?(if yes, pls spec prop. def.).

Comment: @ScottLundberg: does (the|any) RFC forbid to _duplicate_ broadcast packets? ('duplicate' instead of 'forward') (by 'broadcast packets' I mean '_limited_ broadcast packets') (by 'duplicate' I mean 'duplicate _by the host_ who has _sent_ the broadcast packet in the first place'). I ask because I don't know ;)

Comment: Also, what if metric is the same for all NICs for the limited broadcast packet entries in the routing table? How should the limited broadcast packet be sent then?

Comment: Hmm, or actually, I'm wrong on the _physical_ network part as I may have mutliple L2 interfaces connected to the same _physical_ network? (i.e. 3 bonded NICs? to increase traffic)

Comment: And, what's the purpose of a limited broadcast then? It looks like a limited broadcast _works_ just like a directed broadcast, except that if we actually generate a limited broadcast, the broadcast is sent to the first best matched network in the routing table (instead to a network / to an interface that we've explicitly specified in the _directed_ broadcast packet). Limited broadcast packet: 255.255.255.255/32, Directed broadcast packet examples: 192.168.3.255/24, 10.255.255.255/8, 157.17.255.255/15.